# How to ignore value increasing rows in Oracle11

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

So i have a table where there is a list of values that i need to order by date and ignore the rows where the number is greater than the previous number. Take the following table:

```
Date            Value
01/01/2017      10
01/02/2017      9
01/03/2017      8
01/04/2017      10//Ignore this because previous entry is less(8<10)
01/05/2017      9...
```

So what i what is when i do a select is to return:

```
10
9
8
9
```

Is this even possible using just a query?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So basically you are searching for longest trend? Please describe what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: No just want to ignore rows where previous entry is less

Comment: Both below solutions work. Thanks so much you are all awesom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `lag()`:

```
select value
from (select t.*, lag(value) over (order by date) as prev_value
      from t
     ) t
where prev_value is null or prev_value > value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`LAG`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, LAG(Value,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY Date) AS prev
  FROM your_table
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE Value > prev;
```